# How would I create a proper UPDATE statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have to update *Lseq* field in Table_A with values from Table_B *seq* field.

**TABLE_A**

```
ID  | OrderNumber  | Lseq | SKU  | CustOrdNumber
----+--------------+------+------+---------------
523 | DTCI102597-A |      | C123 | 102597-RPI
524 | DTCI102597-A |      | C123 | 102597-RPI
525 | DTCI102597-A |      | C123 | 102597-RPI
```

**TABLE_B**

```
ID  | order_no     | seq   | sku
----+--------------+-------+---------
201 | DTCI102597-A | 16384 | C123
202 | DTCI102597-A | 32768 | C4302716
203 | DTCI102597-A | 49152 | C123
204 | DTCI102597-A | 65536 | C4302716
205 | DTCI102597-A | 81920 | C123
206 | DTCI102597-A | 98304 | C4302720
```

My end result should be

**Table_A**

```
ID  | OrderNumber  | Lseq  | SKU  | CustOrdNumber
----+--------------+-------+------+--------------
523 | DTCI102597-A | 16384 | C123 | 102597-RPI
524 | DTCI102597-A | 49152 | C123 | 102597-RPI
525 | DTCI102597-A | 81920 | C123 | 102597-RPI
```

Here is my current script that is not working it doesn't return all the Lseq numbers.

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
SET LSeq = B.seq
FROM TABLE_B as B
INNER JOIN TABLE_A AS A ON A.OrderNumber = B.ORDER_NO
                        AND A.sku = B.sku
```

Comment: I think with the way your current tables are structured, you'd need to use `row_number()` to join the tables.

Comment: How would I do this, dont think I never used row_number function

Answer (score 1):

Since your OrderNumber / SKU combination is not unique, you need some way of joining the rows on their row number. The first ID in table A needs to match the first ID in table B, the second ID in table A needs to match the second ID in table B, etc.

One way of achieving this is using the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) window function.

For example,

```
UPDATE A
SET LSeq = B.Seq
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNumber, SKU ORDER BY ID)
    FROM tableA
) A
JOIN
(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_no, SKU ORDER BY ID)
    FROM tableB
) B ON B.SKU = A.SKU 
    AND B.order_no = A.OrderNumber 
    AND B.RN = A.RN; -- First ID joins to first ID, second ID joins to second ID, etc.
```

Comment: thank you for the direction, I did appy it to larger data set tables and I am not getting the desired results it works fine with the example tables but not for the real larger data sets and I was wondering if the the tables need to be in some relational sort to each other for the joined columns?

Comment: If you're not getting the desired results, it's _probably_ because the number of records in one table isn't the same as the number of records in the other. Without an explicit join on something unique (like an ID), it's hard to do this sort of thing when the data in the tables is not necessarily aligned.

Comment: Thank you, I think it is because two tables are not equal. What I will do is create temp table with the RN fields in each where I can join them and do the UPDATE statement